# Profiling functions in the cleanest way

Tags: typescript

I would like to profile a large number of functions and would like to make it as clean as possible.

If a generic function looks like this:

```
export function foo(
  param1: string,
  param2?: Date | undefined,
) : string {
  if (param1 == "foo") return "foo";
  return "bar"
}
```

then with profiling it turns into this:

```
export function foo(
  param1: string,
  param2?: Date | undefined,
) : string {
  const start = startFunction("foo"); // Stores the start time of the function
  const result = fooImpl(param1, param2);
  endFunction(start); // Records how long the function took to complete.
  return result; 
}

export function fooImpl(
  param1: string,
  param2?: Date | undefined,
) : string {
  if (param1 == "foo") return "foo";
  return "bar"
}
```

It seems like this could be cleaner, especially because I have to customize the argument list for each and every functions.  Any suggestions of how to make this cleaner?

Comment: Decorators may help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a generic function that returns a wrapped function:

```js
function addProfiling<FunctionType extends (...args: any[]) => any>(
  f: FunctionType
): FunctionType {
  return function (...args) {
    console.time(f.name)
    const returnValue = f(...args)
    console.timeEnd(f.name)
    return returnValue
  } as FunctionType
}
// using console.time here for portabilty, you can replace this with your own profiling implementation

function message1000(message: string): void {
  for (let index = 0; index < 1000; index++) {
    console.log(message1000)
  }
}

const profiledMessage1000 = addProfiling(message1000)
// type is correctly inferred: const profiledMessage1000: (message: string) => void
```

async version:

```js
function addAsyncProfiling<FunctionType extends (...args: any[]) => Promise<any>>(
  f: FunctionType
): FunctionType {
  return async function (...args) {
    console.time(f.name)
    const returnValue = await f(...args)
    console.timeEnd(f.name)
    return returnValue
  } as FunctionType
}

function wait(milliseconds: number): Promise<void> {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, milliseconds))
}

const profiledWait = addAsyncProfiling(wait)
// type is correctly inferred: const profiledWait: (milliseconds: number) => Promise<void>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could create a higher-order function that takes a function and returns a new function with logic added. In simple words: a Higher-Order function is a function that receives a function as an argument or returns the function as output.

This would allow you to avoid repeating the logic in each function and only add it once.

Here's a quick HOF example:

```
function withProfiling<T extends (...args: any[]) => any>(fn: T, functionName?: string): T {
  return function(this: any, ...args: Parameters<T>): ReturnType<T> {
    /* do something here */
  } as T;
}
```

withProfiling takes a function as its first argument and an optional function name as its second argument. It returns a new function that wraps the original function.

To use this higher-order function, you would simply call it with your original function as an argument.